# Error: Failed to resolve: com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.6-2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, arcgis

I followed [this guide](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/install-and-set-up.htm) to add an ArcGIS map to my app, but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to resolve: com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.6-2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the correct dependencies, libraries, permissions, etc?

Comment: Could you add some of your code or screenshots of your project's set up? It's possible something was missed in the tutorial and it's not working because of that.

Comment: Well, you need to add every single item there, if not... It won't work.

Comment: screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8L-U960-aqxaEFhLWJ2eFc1LUU/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8L-U960-aqxTjlYVndXNl9XaE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @FelixChen FYI your screenshot links don't work anymore. If you still have the screenshots, you might want to edit your question and add the screenshots to the question.

Answer (score 7):

From your screenshots, you put your `maven` block in the wrong place. You put it under `buildscript -> repositories`, but according to https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/install-and-set-up.htm it should be under `allprojects -> repositories`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // add the esri arcgis maven repo
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis'
        }
    }
}
```

The way you did it in your screenshot would cause the error you see.

Comment: This solution worked and i am amazed why it wasn't marked as answer. @Felix Chen : If this did work for you, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, the URL has been changed to https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis according to this [announcement](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/developers/announcements/announcement-to-developers-using-arcgis-runtime-sdks-for-android-and-java/). So now you have to do it like this.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis'
        }
    }
}
```